# Can a constexpr constructor initialize a base class using the address of a member (GCC+MSVC vs Clang)?

Tags: c++, inheritance, initialization, language-lawyer, constexpr

Consider the following piece of code:

```cpp
struct base {
  int* base_member;
};

struct obj_t {
    constexpr int* data() {
        return &m_data;
    }
    int m_data;
};

class derived : public base {
public:
  constexpr derived() :
    base{derived_member.data()},
    derived_member{42}
  {}

private:
  obj_t derived_member;
};

constexpr derived g_obj{};
```

What happens here is that the class `derived` initializes its base class `base` using its member `derived_member`. I would usually consider this UB, as base classes are initialized before derived class members. As such it would be a compile-time error if used in a constant expression.

The reality is different though. While GCC and MSVC accept this code, Clang rejects it ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5qefc6sxx)). The question is **which compiler is right**?

The first intuition supports Clang and its output saying that:

```
error: field 'derived_member' is uninitialized when used here [-Werror,-Wuninitialized]
error: constexpr variable 'g_obj' must be initialized by a constant expression
note: member call on object outside its lifetime is not allowed in a constant expression
...
```

Note that Clang rejects it with both `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror` as well as with `-Wno-everything`.

On the other hand, I have a theory of why might GCC and MSVC accept this. The thing is, that the `derived_member` isn't accessed itself, only its address is taken inside the `data()` member function. This address is theoretically known by the compiler and doesn't depend on the object being initialized.

The problem with this theory is that the `data()` member function is invoked on the object, which usually requires the object to be already constructed. I wondered what would happen if I would take the address manually, using the `&` operator. It turns out that in this case, the compiler trinity accepts the code unanimously ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ravKa1bss)).

I also test using `std::addressof`. In this case, all three compilers accept the code ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/j78zj4jf6)).

Finally, I also tested a crude manual implementation of `addressof` that looks like this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
constexpr T* my_addressof(T& arg) noexcept {
    return &arg;
}
```

In this case, all three compilers also accept the code ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Taf31dnWb)).

As such, what is the correct behavior, and which compiler/-s is/are right?

#### Edit 1 - background information

I will add some background, in case someone is interested. I discovered this problem while working on a project called [PaSh](https://github.com/binpash/pash). The problem occurred in a file I wrote used to create a `constexpr` C++ wrapper over the UNIX function `getopt_long`. The problem was masked in using `std::array` and its member function `data`. The permalink to the broken (not accepted by Clang) version is [here](https://github.com/binpash/pash/blob/ddf1378fa9cff0eb6929cf7cfaa1a4e31b260820/runtime/agg/cpp/common/command_opts.h). I fixed it in [a recent commit](https://github.com/binpash/pash/pull/311/commits/d8c0a443032ba49c1cae9cb99901a0fd5a1d7e16) and that version is available [here](https://github.com/binpash/pash/blob/b263ee6a6ea805c9d567f9edfec85990fd554828/runtime/agg/cpp/common/command_opts.h).

#### Edit 2 - clarification about storage duration

After seeing the answer by @KitsuneSan I want to clarify that my question is about a more general problem than the one given in the first example code snippet. The fact that `g_obj` has static storage duration and consequently `g_obj.derived_member.m_data` also has it is just a feature of that example. In the following example, the `derived` class object is temporary, so the argument that `m_data` has static storage duration no longer applies:

```cpp
struct base; // as above
struct obj_t; // as above
class derived; // as above

constexpr int dummy = [](){
    derived g_obj{};
    return 13;
}();
```

In this case, the code is accepted by GCC and MSVC while being rejected by Clang, just like the original ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/EzMEKr488)).

Comment: Consider that `base{derived_member.data()}` is UB because calling a member function on an object outside of it's lifetime is UB, but `base{&derived_member.m_data}` (Or turning `data` into a friend function and calling `base{data(derived_member)}` instead) isn't, since no lvalue-to-rvalue (thus access) of `derived_member` (nor `derived_member.m_data`) is done

Answer (score 0):

According to the standard Section 7.7:

> If E satisfies the constraints of a core constant expression, but
> evaluation of E would evaluate an operation that has undefined
> behavior as specified in [library] through [thread], or an invocation
> of the va_­start macro ([cstdarg.syn]), it is unspecified whether E is
> a core constant expression.

Basically, it looks like compilers are *allowed* to reject a constexpr expression that triggers UB, but not *required* to. The example you gave is tricky because there are several layers of indirection, so I'm guessing the compiler loses track of whether the memory pointed to is initialized (because it is valid constexpr storage, at least).

Comment: The quote you mention is for library ub. The one about language ub is this one http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.7

Comment: Ah, you're right, the language you're referencing was added as a correction to C++11 <https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1313>. Maybe compiler authors just never completely fixed it.

The standard also says here: <http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#11.2> that a pointer can be considered constexpr as long as it points to an object with static duration, which is true in this case, so the pointer is perfectly fine unless it's dereferenced.

Comment: @KitsuneSan I added clarification to the question that the fact that `g_obj` has static storage duration is coincidental and not a part of the problem that the question is trying to address. The problem occurs also when the object doesn't have static storage duration.